# Verifying a proof of subsets.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Prove or disprove. If $f(A) \subseteq f(B)$ then $A \subseteq B$

Let y be arbitrary.

$f(A)$ means $\exists a \in A (f(a)=y)$

$f(B)$ means $\exists b \in B (f(b)=y)$

but $\forall a \in A \exists ! y \in f(a)(f(a)=y)$

and $\forall b \in B \exists ! y \in f(b)(f(b)=y)$

Therefore if $f(a)=y=f(b)$, then $a = b$. This along with the given that $f(A) \subseteq f(B)$ shows that $A \subseteq B$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:  Consider a constant function,  for instance,  $f(x)=0$,  with domain $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

As @Alan said, this is false. Take $E=\{0,1\}$ and $F=\{0\}$, and define $f:E\to F$ by $f(0)=f(1)=0$. Then you have $f(\{0\})=\{0\}\subset f(\{1\})=\{0\}$ whereas $\{0\}\not\subset\{1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f$ is *injective* and that $f(A) \subseteq f(B)$. Let $x \in A$. Then $f(x) \in f(A) \subseteq f(B)$ and $f(x) = f(y)$ for some $y \in B$. But since $f$ is injective, $x = y$ and $x \in B$.

On the other hand, if $f$ is *not injective*, then there is distinct $x \neq y$ with $f(x) = f(y)$. Let $A = \{x, y\}, B = \{y\}$. Then $f(A) \subseteq f(B)$ but $A$ is not in $B$.

For counterexample, take $f(x) = x^2$ with $A = \{-2,2\}$.

Answer (score 0):

If codomain $Y$ of function $f:X\to Y$ is a singleton then $f(A)=Y$ for **any** non-empty set $A\subseteq X$.

So $f(A)\subseteq f(B)$ is true for any pair of nonempty subsets of $X$.

If $X$ is has more than one element then nonempty sets $A, B\subseteq X$  exist with $A\nsubseteq B$.

This proves that the statement is not true.